# Proving the limit laws for convergent series

Tags: real-analysis

Prove the following limit laws for series: 
(a) If series ak converges and c ∈ R then series(cak) converges and series cak = cak
(b) If Series ak and bk both converge then (ak + bk) converges and (ak + bk)=ak+bk

For the first, I began my proof by stating what it means for the series ak to converge and then set it to the limit of the partial sum. Then, I multiplied the series and the limit by c. However, I don't know how this show that c x the series converges.
For the second part, I had the same idea.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please try to learn MathJax and use it to make your posts more clear for your readers.

Answer (score 1):

Since a series is simply a sequence of partial sums, all you have to do is refer to the limit theorems for convergent sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on right track. You have to use properties of limits to prove this. Let's say a series converges. Then it should have a finite limit, say l. Then $lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} a_k =l$. Now, to obtain new series, we multiply by c. So using properties of limits,  we can write $lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} ca_k = c.lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} a_k =cl $, which is finite, (c and l both being finite). Hence the new series also converges.In this way you can prove.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

$$|ca_k-ca|\le|c||a_k-a|$$

and

$$|(a_k+b_k)-(a+b)|\le|a_k-a|+|b_k-b|.$$